# How to drag the map instead of the page below it? (mobile)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drag

I have a google maps window inside my home page. It works perfectly in a PC, but in a mobile device dragging the map drags the page below it and not the map.
You can test it here (click the "GPS Map" button at the top right):
http://luis.impa.br/photo/1407_Obidos/index.html

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

L.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would have been useful and educational. Still.... no answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but a partial one.

I realized that the dragging of the map is disabled when the browser is set to some kind of "desktop mode", i.e., when the browser identifies itself as working in a non-touch device. So Google maps understands that there is no touch screen.

So, in order to drag maps, you do need to assure that your browser is not set to a "desktop mode".

Still, I don't know (or even if it is possible) how to allow dragging of the map under "desktop mode".